# Compare rows in group with specific value postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, compare, pgadmin

Edit: when 5 or 9 does not exist, i need a null value (or another flag)

I have 3 columns. SECTION, STATUS and NAME. Within a SECTION there are a maximum of 10 rows (STATUS 1 to 10). I have to compare the value of NAME for STATUS 5 and 9 within a SECTION. AND then indicate if those 2 NAMES (for STATUS 5 and 9) are the same for each SECTION.

section status name
1      5       a
1      6       a
1      9       b
2      4       c
2      5       d
2      9       d
2      10     d
3       5       e
3       10    e

Desired output

```
Section equalnames
1      no
2      yes
3      null/flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a boolean instead of strings and just use aggregation with filtering:

```
select group, min(name) = max(name) as names_equal_flag
from t
where status in (5, 9)
group by group;
```

Note that `group` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.  I assume you have a more appropriate name in your actual data.

If you want a string, you can use `case`:

```
select group,
       (case when min(name) = max(name) then 'yes' else 'no' end) as names_equal_flag
from t
where status in (5, 9)
group by group;
```

Comment: Thank you. But the min is not always the 5 right?

Comment: The column name is not really group

Comment: Omg the last one worked. Thank you so much Gordon. But what does this min and max do??