# Compare rows with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Edit: when 5 or 9 does not exist, i need a null value (or another flag)

I have 3 columns. SECTION, STATUS and NAME. Within a SECTION there are a maximum of 10 rows (STATUS 1 to 10). I have to compare the value of NAME for STATUS 5 and 9 within a SECTION. AND then indicate if those 2 NAMES (for STATUS 5 and 9) are the same for each SECTION.

```
section status name
1      5       a
1      6       a
1      9       b
2      4       c
2      5       d
2      9       d
2      10      d
3      5       e
3      10      e
```

Desired output

```
Section equalnames
1      no
2      yes
3      null/flag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
a.section, 
case 
  when a.name = b.name then 'YES'
  when a.name <> b.name then 'NO' 
  when (a.name is null or b.name is null) then 'NULL' end
from
(select * from <table> where status = 5) a
full join (select * from <table> where status = 9) b
  on a.section = b.section
```

Comment: Bullseye. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Mae how does this answer your question? The results do not include section 3: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=84804a80a732e42d1dc27a1650fd2a98

Comment: @Mae I see that this is the 2nd time you ask the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370924/compare-rows-in-group-with-specific-value-postgresql and in both cases you accepted an answer that does not solve your problem because it does not return your expected results. Check the link in my previous comment for a proof.

Comment: Modified the query to a full join to handle cases where either of the statuses is missing. This method is a quick and dirty solution.  The conditional aggregation others have proposed will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT section,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 5 THEN name END) = 
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 9 THEN name END) equalnames
FROM tablename
WHERE status IN (5, 9)
GROUP BY section
ORDER BY section
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f4a1181a533bd9e9cb632a910bac26b).
Results:

```
section | equalnames
------- | ----------
      1 | f         
      2 | t         
      3 | null
```

Comment: Thanks so much. What does this MAX do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a left join  on same table for 5 and 9

```
select a.section, a.status s5, a.name n5, b.status b9, b.name n9 
, case when a.name = b.name the yes 
       when a.name is null or b.name is nul the NULL 
       when a.name <> b.name then no end equalname
from my_table a 
left join my_table b a.section = b.section and a.status =5 and b.status=9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select section,
       (case when min(case when status = 5 then name end) = 
                  min(case when status = 9 then name end) 
             then 'yes'
             when count(case when status in (5, 9) then status end) < 2
             then 'null/flag'
             else 'no'
        end)                  
from t
group by section;
```

No `join` is needed and I would not advise one for this problem.

Comment: Thanks so much. Why not inner join?

Comment: This doenst work when there are two 5's and no 9. It returns 'no'. With the join it return nothing (which is what I want). With the join it return double rows when there are two 5's and a 9 but i can remove the duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: @Mae . . . It is very easy to fix that.  You have no such examples in your data.  Note that the `full join` method will return duplicates if you can have multiple rows with the same status.

Comment: You are right, it was not in my example data. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A more optimised solution could be with cte and window function:

```
with cte as (
select section,  count(status)over(partition by section,name order by section) count_with_same_name,
count(status)over(partition by section order by section) count_with_different_name
from tname where status in (5,9))
select  section,(case when (max(count_with_same_name)=2) then 'Yes' when (max(count_with_different_name)=2) then 'No' else 'null/flag' end)
from cte
group by section
```

**Output:**

[image]